# Centring text with font awesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to centre a line of text with a font awesome icon in it. However, the icon hovers above the text rather than below it and does not extend the height of the container

[image]

My HTML is the following:

```
<div id='container'>
  Some text
  <br>
  <i class='fas fa-camera'></i>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: max-content;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 }
#container i {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: What about using flex  layout manager with two rows first row is for text and second for icon and use center alignment  see  this  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

add `text-align: center;` to `#container` and give your icon it's own element tag. `<i>` is not processed as a block element.

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: max-content;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
 }
#container i {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  Some text
  <br>
  <div><i class='fas fa-camera'>test</i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work. The icon remains in place. Font awesome icons aren't treated as text and this is the root of the problem.

Comment: @Tom888 Try that